# I installed a python package (langchain) using "pip install", but it can't be imported

Tags: python, langchain

I installed it globally using `pip install langchain` but I can't import it on my python code.

I am using PyCharm and VS Code, `from langchain.llms import OpenAI`. the package works well, I did  on my work pc, but it doesn't work on my home pc.

I simply typed `from langchain.llms import OpenAI` and it says `No module named 'langchain`, I also checked using pip list, and it shows langchain, I even tried using the File Explorer to go to Python311/Lib/site-packages, it is there but I can't import it.

I also tried installing other packages, and it works well aside from langchain.

Comment: Can you tell us about what OS you are using, and what exact commands you use to install the package and run your script ?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 22H2, same with my work pc. I simply used `pip install langchain` and `pip install openai` as it was said so in the documentation. Completely the same with my work pc, including python 3.11, and pip 23.1.2 which is the latest.

Comment: Have you used [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) before? Could it be that you are running the code from a virtual environment and you installed the package outside that environment?

Comment: Use `pip -V` outside your IDE to see where you installed and `print(sys.path)` inside your IDE to see where it is looking. I predict a mismatch.

Comment: lmao, i thought of that but confirmed I wasn't on a virtualenv, then I did:

`import sys
print (sys.executable)`

it said im using python3.10, but when i do `py` on cmd, it says 3.11, so it must mean I have 2 python installations in my home pc. 

I just uninstalled 3.10, Idk what to do next @MarkSetchell

Comment: I don't use an IDE, so am not ideally placed to help, but essentially you need to configure your IDE to use the same Python that you pip-installed your package into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try below steps.

Create a virtual environment using the command

```
python -m venv my_venv_name
```

Activate the virtual environment by executing source

```
 my_venv_name/bin/activate
```

PIP install libraries

```
pip install langchain
pip install """Other required libraries like OpenAI etc.
```

You should now successfully able to import

```
from langchain.llm import OpenAI
```

Lastly when executing the code, make sure you are pointing to correct interpreter (In Pycharm)

[image]

Comment: I got it now, I was just new to IDEs and such. I have two python installations, and the interpreter was using an older version. Thank you for showing the settings, I didn't know how to change the versions before til you said there was something like that. :)